# File::Temp version 0.18 required--this is only version 16

Tags: php, perl, cpan, request-tracker

I ran YUM on a server running BestPractical's RT. Now Apache won't start. Looking at the error log I get this error:

> File::Temp version 0.18 required--this is only version 0.16 at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/MIME/Tools.pm line 14.

I ran CPAN and did install File::Temp and it says it already has the latest version (0.22). Why is it giving me this error?

Comment: I realized that it appears Linux has two copies of Perl installed. One in usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8 and another in usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.13.9...I think this is the issue, but not sure how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have `/usr/bin/perl` (Perl v5.8.8) with libraries stored in `/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/…`, and then you also have `/usr/local/bin/perl` (Perl v5.13.9) with libraries stored in `/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.13.9/…`. When you updated `File::Spec`, you updated the version used by `/usr/local/bin/perl`, but `/usr/bin/perl` is still using the old version.

You must either update the version of `File::Spec` used by `/usr/bin/perl` or make Apache use `/usr/local/bin/perl`.

To update the version used by `/usr/bin/perl` you can use

```
/usr/bin/perl -MCPAN -we 'CPAN::Shell -> install("File::Spec")'
```

I don't have much experience with Apache, but I am sure there are several ways to make it use `/usr/local/bin/perl`. You could try to place `/usr/local/bin` before `/usr/bin` in the `PATH` environment variable, but that might have other consequences, though.